# jquery mobile - how to pre-fill text input of type date-time-local

Tags: jquery, datetime, mobile, input

In jquery mobile I have a form with a date-time-local input field:

```
<div class="schedule" data-role="fieldcontain">
   <label for="start_at">Start At:</label>
   <input id="start_at" name="start_at" type="datetime-local" value="" />
</div>
```

This input field shows the template [dd-mm-jjjj --:--] on screen to enter a date and time.

But how can you pre-fill such a field with a date and time from a database or with javascript?

I tried to pre-fill it with value "31-12-2013 15:35" and with a date in milliseconds, but nothing works so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/christianheinrichs/dkovm51L/1/)

To prefill the text input you simply do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#start_at").val("2013-12-31T15:35");
});
```

If you want to add seconds and miliseconds add them this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#start_at").val("2013-12-31T15:35:52.52");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. F.i. in Chrome, when you click the down arrow, 2 overlapping datepickers are shown and no timepicker. Furthermore the jquery ui js and css conflict with the jquery mobile js and css.

Comment: Check the new solution.
I tested it in Chrome and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

The date has to be in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: `yyyy-HH-mm'T'mm:ss` so you just need to set the value as `"2013-12-31T15:35"`

```
<div class="schedule" data-role="fieldcontain">
   <label for="start_at">Start At:</label>
   <input id="start_at" name="start_at" type="datetime-local" value="2013-12-31T15:35" />
</div>
```